# Evaluating a line integral over a curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I'm trying to solve the problem $\int_C x\sin(y)ds$, where C is the line segment from (0,1) to (4,4). This is my solution, which is wrong. I was hoping someone could tell me where I took a misstep.

Parametric equations: $x=4t$ and $y=1+3t$,

$\int_0^14t\sin(3t+1) \sqrt({4^2}+{3^2})dt$

$20\int_0^1t\sin(3t+1)dt$

after using integration by parts:

$20[\frac{-t}{3}\cos(1+3t)+\frac{1}{9}\sin(1+3t)]|^1_0$

which after simplifying gives:

$\frac{20}{9}[\sin(4)-3\cos(4)].$

Comment: what is the result that you are trying to get?

Comment: It looks like you just didn't plug in zero

Comment: When I plug in 0, I get 0/3 in the first term and sin(1) in the second term, which both would equal 0

Comment: you should get $-sin(1)$ together with the other two terms!

Comment: As soon as I posted that I realized what I said. Its been a long day haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the last passage you have:
$$20\left[-\frac{\cos({4})}{3}+\frac{\sin({4})-\sin({1})}{9}\right] = \frac{20}{9}\left[-3\cos({4})+\sin({4})-\sin({1})\right]$$